# Open and close angle bracket in HAML

Tags: ruby, haml

I found something similar to `%strong><= 5` in a source code.

What does `><`, open close angle brackets, do in HAML?

Comment: _Offtopic_: do they frown?

Comment: Post the code of the source haml file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html

> #### Whitespace Removal: `>` and `<`
>
> `>` and `<` give you more control over the whitespace near a tag. `>` will remove all whitespace surrounding a tag, while `<` will remove all whitespace immediately within a tag. You can think of them as alligators eating the whitespace: `>` faces out of the tag and eats the whitespace on the outside, and `<` faces into the tag and eats the whitespace on the inside. They’re placed at the end of a tag definition, after class, id, and attribute declarations but before `/` or `=`.

Comment: Order doesn't seem to matter, both `><` and `<>` produce identical results.